# How can I deny direct access to a python file stored on a webserver with help of an .htaccess file but still allow access to it from another file?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a XAMP Server with Apache running on a Windows PC.
In the root directory of the webserver there is a index.php file which starts via command line (shell_exec) a pythonscript in the same directory, which returns a result to the php file.

```
root-dir/
  -index.php
  -script.py
```

Now I want to deny the direct access (e.g. via Browser) to script.py with an .htaccess file.
But what still must be possible is, that via HTTPRequest some client application can access the index.php file and gets the result from script.py indirectly from the index.php file.

How can I do this with an .htaccess File?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply block it as you would any other file. Providing `script.py` is not being requested over HTTP from `index.php` then it won't be blocked, since `.htaccess` won't be processed.

For Example:

```
<Files "script.py">
    Require all denied
</Files>
```

Attempting to request `script.py` directly via a browser (or via any HTTP request) will result in a 403 Forbidden. (Assumes Apache 2.4)